# Google Analytics only showing people who are logged in to Wordpress

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress

We are using Google Analyticator with WordPress to manage our analytics, and pages that aren't viewable unless you're already a member are showing up as the most popular pages. It seems that, since people have to log in first, that those should be first, rather than hidden pages.

What should settings be for Google Analyticator when there are hidden pages?

Comment: There is a difference between "GA is only showing private pages" and "private pages are the most popular". Does the public pages are shown in GA or not?

Answer (score 0):

on your footer try this.

```
<?php if(is_user_logged_in()) { ?>
 // Here your analytics code 
 <?php } ?>
```

I guess, it will get you the logged in users only.